# Первые два байта содержат максимальную длину строки, которая определяется при инициализации. Признак конца строки - символ '\0'

Tags: c

Вот что есть

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef char* string1;

void InitStr(string1* st, unsigned n) {
    *st = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * n + sizeof(unsigned) * 2);
    st[0] = n / 2 + n % 2;
    st[1] = n / 2;
}

int main() {
    unsigned size;
    scanf_s("%u", &size);
    string1 str1;
    InitStr(&str1, size);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: И что? Вопрос в чем? А вообще-то, понятно, что бред, но вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Как сделать то что написано в задании

Comment: Мне нужно сделать строку первые 2 байта которая хранят её длинну

Comment: используй паскаль, в нём вроде такие строки. в си используются ASCIZ строки.

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
char * InitStr(unsigned short int n)
{
    assert(sizeof(n) == 2);
    char * st = malloc(sizeof(char)*(n+1) + sizeof(n));
    memset(st,0,sizeof(char)*(n+1) + sizeof(n));
    *(unsigned short int *)st = n;
    return st;
}

int main() {

    unsigned short int size;
    scanf_s("%hu", &size);
    char * str1 = InitStr(size);
    //....
    free(str1);
}
```

Теоретически можно спорить о strict aliasing, но на практике — вполне работоспособно.

Как более удобный для работы вариант:

```
char * InitStr(unsigned short int n)
{
    assert(sizeof(n) == 2);
    char * st = malloc(sizeof(char)*(n+1) + sizeof(n));
    memset(st,0,sizeof(char)*(n+1) + sizeof(n));
    *(unsigned short int *)st = n;
    return st+2;
}


unsigned short int StrLen(char* s)
{
    return *(unsigned short int *)(s-2);
}

int main() {

    unsigned short int size;
    scanf_s("%hu", &size);
    char * str1 = InitStr(size);
    //....
    free(str1-2);
}
```

https://ideone.com/wDSrdY

Comment: `sizeof(char)` **всегда равен 1**. По определению, поскольку в C/C++ `char` это минмальный адресуемый элемент данных.  / (интересно, кто-тто минуснул за это?)

Comment: Можете ещё чутка помочь. Я пытаюсь переделать то что вы скинули под то что мне надо по заданию. Но программа выдает абсолютно не тот размер который я ввожу. (По заданию должен быть тип string1 и функция InitStr типа void которая на входе должна получать переменную типа string1)

Comment: Я то что у меня получилось как ответ выложил

Comment: @avp Это делает код неверным?...

Comment: @Harry, нет, работать  он будет правильно. Только выглядит из-за лишних букв некрасиво

Comment: @avp Ну, тогда надо `char * st; memset(st = malloc(n+3),0,n+3);` :)

Comment: @Harry, или `char *st = calloc(n + 3, 1);` -)

Comment: @avp Логично...

Answer (score 0):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef char* string1;

void InitStr(string1 st, unsigned short int n)
{
    assert(sizeof(n) == 2);
    st = malloc(sizeof(char) * (n + 1) + sizeof(n));
    memset(st, 0, sizeof(char) * (n + 1) + sizeof(n));
    (unsigned short int*)st = n;
}

unsigned short int StrLen(string1 s)
{
    return (unsigned short int*)(s - 2);
}

int main() {

    unsigned short int size;
    string1 str;
    scanf_s("%hu", &size);
    InitStr(&str, size);

    printf("%hu\n", StrLen(&str));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Я пытаюсь переделать код который скинули выше под то что мне надо по заданию. Но программа выдает абсолютно не тот размер который я ввожу. (По заданию должен быть тип string1 и функция InitStr типа void которая на входе должна получать переменную типа string1)

Comment: Обратите внимание, вы дали ответ. На ответ вам никто не ответит. [Задайте новый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) и сошлитесь на текуший, если есть взаимосвязь. Это сообщение, пожалуйста, удалите.

Comment: Послушайте, я дал ответ. Работающий. Зачем вы стали его менять?